# Splitting a pdf-file into 2 pdf's (one contining equal pages etc...)

Tags: bash, pdf

I have a 600 pages long pdf file.
I would love to be able to split it in different pdf files,
one containing odd-numbered pages: 1,3,5,7,9,11 etc.
and another file containing even-numbered pages: 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 etc.

Could anyone help me create something like that ?

Answer (score 2):

use `pdftk`. as simple as:

```
pdftk input.pdf cat even output even.pdf
pdftk input.pdf cat odd output odd.pdf
```

this will create the even.pdf and odd.pdf files form your input.pdf file.

Answer (score 0):

[pdftk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/) is a nice commandline tool to extract and transform pages from pdf files. Available as a package in Debian and probably also in other distributions.

Answer (score 0):

One excellent option if `pdfk`, but that isn't available on e.g. Fedora due to licensing restrictions. Check out `poppler` (and its various subtools), it includes `pdfseparate`. Or look for `pdfjam`, a tool for futzing around with PDF.